# Checking For a New Line in a Text File

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a code that reads from a file and works with the characters it reads.  The gist is that it has to correct the capitalization errors present in the file it reads.

One particular requirement is that I have to number each line, so I wrote a bit to determine whether or not a each character read is a line break.

```
int fix_caps(char* ch, int* char_in_word, int* line_num){

char a;
ch = &a;

if(a != '\n'){
    return 0;
}else{
    return 1;
}

if(a == ' ')
   *char_in_word = 0;

if(*char_in_word == 1)
   a = toupper(a);

if(*char_in_word > 1)
   a = tolower(a);

char_in_word++;

}
```

However, the function this is in always returns 0, when it should return 1 at the end of each line.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's a couple things I don't understand: you're assigning ch to the address of an uninitiated variable, and the function will always exit at the `if` at the top of the function; it will never get to the `if(a == ' ')` part because both legs of the if statement cause a return.

Comment: You let `ch` point to `&a`, but `a` is uninitialized. So it's more than likely always `!= '\n'`. I think what you wanted to do was `char a = *ch`

Comment: Thanks, I wanted it to be `char a = *ch`.  Unfortunately, it still doesn't correct the case of the characters passed into it.

Comment: @reidf You are changing the value of `a` which is local to the function and hence has no effect on your letters outside of that scope. Either assign that value at the end to `*ch` or use `*ch` throughout the function, omitting `a` completely.

Answer (score 1):

```
the execution will never get beyond this 'if control block:

char a;
ch = &a;

if(a != '\n'){
   return 0;
}else{
    return 1;
}

there is a few reasons it 'always' returns 0
1) 'a' is on the stack and could contain anything.
2) the chances of the 'trash' that is on the stack where 'a'
   is located are 255:1 against the trash happening to contain
   a new line character.

nothing beyond the 'if control block is ever executed because
an 'if' control block only has two execution paths 
and both paths contain a return statement.
```

Comment: Format your answer properly. Don't add text by indenting it as code.